# Google Maps Find Place API locationbias causing zero results

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use the locationbias feature of the Find Place API to provide more relevant results for my searches.  I have tried both a point and a rectangle, and in both cases my query returns zero results.  However, if I remove the bias completely I do get a result.  Why is a location that I know is within the boundary of the rectangle not being returned?  Also, the field is called location**bias** implying it will prefer Places near this location but not force strict boundaries, so why am I getting zero results?

Here is an example GET: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Ariel%20Dunes%201%20Unit%20308%20Seascape%20Resort&inputtype=textquery&locationbias=rectangle%3A30.119056%2C-86.527098%7C30.444872%2C-85.705723&fields=geometry%2Flocation%2Cname%2Cplace_id

Response:

`{ "candidates" : [], "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"}`

Without locationbias: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?inputtype=textquery&fields=geometry%2Flocation%2Cname%2Cplace_id&input=Ariel%20Dunes%201%20Unit%20308%20Seascape%20Resort

Response:
`{ "candidates" : [ { "geometry" : { "location" : { "lat" : 30.377608, "lng" : -86.366795 } }, "name" : "Ariel Dunes I (ADI) at Seascape Resort", "place_id" : "ChIJF5B7IoRbkYgRQWjAZv0-wUI" } ], "status" : "OK" }`

For clarity, here's the decoded locationbias used above:  `rectangle:30.119056,-86.527098|30.444872,-85.705723`

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#locationbias) this should be the southwest corner of the rectangle followed by the northeast corner of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to my use of Postman.  Postman implicitly encodes the query string.  Disabling this feature allowed me to use a literal colon between the shape and the coordinates which corrected the behavior.